# Why is this UIScrollView-based carousel not responding to horizontal swipes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, carousel

I have, slightly simplified:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
    200 /*self.view.frame.size.width*/,
    (self.view.frame.size.height - 20) / 3)];

UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note1"];
CGSize cardSize = [cardImage size];
CJSHCardView *cardView = [[CJSHCardView alloc] initWithImage:cardImage];
[cardView rotate];
[cardView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[cardView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, cardSize.width * scale, cardSize.height * scale)];
[cardView setDescription:@"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"];
[cardView setOnWeb:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
[scrollView addSubview:cardView];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    UIImage *noteImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note2"];
    CGSize noteSize2 = [noteImage2 size];
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:noteImage2];
    CGRect bounds2 = imageView2.bounds;
    CJSHCardView *noteView2 = [[CJSHCardView alloc] initWithImage:noteImage2];
    [noteView2 rotate];
    [noteView2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [noteView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(100 + 100 * i, 20, noteSize2.width * scale, noteSize2.height * scale)];
    [scrollView addSubview:noteView2];
}
[containerView addSubview:scrollView];
```

At either 200 pixels wide or the commented out width, it displays a certain number of images, with the rightmost image sharply cut off. However, the UIScrollView isn't scrolling. I've tried left and right (single) finger swipes, and the images haven't moved a pixel.

What is wrong here? Do I need to do additional configuration to get carousel-like scrolling? Is there a better class for implementing a carousel that scrolls on a single dimension?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For implementing carousels on iOS , I have found this project to be really flexible in its implementation and easy to use :

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

There are good examples included which can bring you upto speed on the usage.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks; looking into it.

Comment: I'm looking at it, and it seems, to put it in positive terms, industrial strength. The "iOS Basic" demo was at least as involved as I would expect for coding things myself; I'm not looking for an ultimate carousel that would field any use case / requirements I would have, just a basic non-jet-powered carousel that uses perhaps UIScrollView to allow swiping across one dimension and having basic scrolling behaviour.

Comment: Or maybe you could expand your answer to include an array of images at different positions in their parent view, and appropriate use of a carousel to allow swiping through the parent view.